# Is it possible to get consistent APNG support in modern browsers?

Tags: animation, safari, apng

I have inherited a legacy project containing some 20+ APNG files that are considered instrumental to the design of the site. However, for whatever reason, Safari plays these APNG files twice where every other browser I have tested them in plays them only once because they were created with the loop count ([num_plays](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification#.60acTL.60:_The_Animation_Control_Chunk)) set to 1. This is standard because 0 means loop forever.

I understand APNG may be considered a thing of the past at this point; but, assuming I cannot change this part of the project, do I have any means of getting Safari to play the animations only once as designed? Or am I looking at some rancid Safari only fallback?

Here is an example of one of the images:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all of the images contain as few colors as the example, you could convert them to animated GIFs without loss of quality to avoid a Safari-only fallback (at which you are, indeed, looking without the conversion).

Comment: That would fall under the category of "rancid safari only fallback" - which incidentally is what I am doing but it is hideous beyond hideous with the jaggy nature of gifs and having no alpha support. I wrote an animation library instead and it sort of does the job but its no answer to my question so I won't post it here. Thanks though.

Comment: I should mention it's not obvious on stack overflow that these apngs have a transparent background. The red wave is the only part of the image and that is hugely distorted in gif format.

Comment: I meant "Use animated GIFs in all browsers.", which would fall under the category of "rancid" in all browsers.

Comment: Does your animation library convert an APNG to a PNG[], the elements of which are displayed sequentially by way of canvas.drawImage()?

Comment: No I split them into frames and run a src swap on an image using requestanimationframe. It works but it's not totally there yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the [frame control chunk](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification#.60fcTL.60:_The_Frame_Control_Chunk) of the last frame by setting `delay_num` to 65535 and `delay_den` to 1 so that the first frame does not display again for 65535 s = 18.2 h!

Comment: lol. That's a reasonable work around if it works. I may give that a shot and report back

Comment: Did you give that a shot?